# logstash add array in document

Tags: logstash

I would like to import data from my postgresql database into my elasticsearch database.

I have an appointments index, in this index I would like to add a persons field (list of people in an appointment).

here is my logstash configuration file and a sample document.

thank you.

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/app"
        jdbc_user => "postgres"
        jdbc_password => "admin"
        jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
        jdbc_driver_library => "postgresql-42.2.21.jar"
        statement => "select id::text,trim(firstname),trim(lastname) from persons"
    }
}
filter {
    ruby {
        code => "
            event['persons'].each{|subdoc| subdoc['persons'] = subdoc['persons']['firstname']}
        "
    }
}
output {
    #stdout { codec => json_lines }
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "127.0.0.1"
        index => "appointments"
        doc_as_upsert => true
        document_id => "%{id}"
    }
}

{
        "_index" : "appointments",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "41",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          ... others fields
          [add array fields]
          ex:
          persons: [{
              "firstname": "firstname1"
          }, {
              "firstname": "firstname2"
          }]
        }
      }
```

UPDATE 2:
I made a mistake, I was modifying the wrong document, I modified the document_id and I added appointment_id in my request.

It still does not work. It replaces my document with what is in the request.

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/app"
        jdbc_user => "postgres"
        jdbc_password => "admin"
        jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
        jdbc_driver_library => "postgresql-42.2.21.jar"
        statement => "select id::text, appointment_id::text,trim(firstname),trim(lastname) from appointments_persons order by created_at"
    }
}
filter {
    aggregate {
        task_id => "%{appointment_id}"
        code => "
            map['persons'] ||= []
        "
        push_map_as_event_on_timeout => true
        timeout_task_id_field => "appointment_id"
        timeout => 10
    }
}
output {
    #stdout { codec => json_lines }
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "127.0.0.1"
        index => "appointments"
        action => update
        doc_as_upsert => true
        document_id => "%{appointment_id}"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are running a very old version of logstash (prior to 5.0) you cannot reference or modify the event by treating it as a hash.

The jdbc filter creates one event for each row in the result set. If you want to combine all the events that have the same [id] you could use an [aggregate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-aggregate.html) filter. Note the warning about setting pipeline.workers to 1 so that all events go through the same instance of the filter. In your case I do not think you need to preserve event order, so pipeline.ordered can be ignored.

You will need to do something similar to example 3 in the documentation.

```
aggregate {
    task_id => "%{id}"
    code => '
        map['persons'] ||= []
        map['persons'] << { "firstname" => event.get("firstname"), "lastname" => event.get("lastname") }
    '
    push_map_as_event_on_timeout => true
    timeout_task_id_field => "id"
    timeout => 10
}
```

If you are using `document_id => "%{appointment_id}"` the event read from the database will be written with to elasticsearch with that document id. Then when the aggregate timeout fires a second document will overwrite that. You might want to add event.cancel to the aggregate code option so that the event from the db does not cloud things.

Comment: thank you. my version is 7.4.1.
i would create array (he doesn't exist).
code doesn't work, array doesn't appear in document
i would create a array like this:
persons: [{"firstname": "A1", "lastname": "A2"}, {"firstname": "B1", "lastname": "B2"}]

Comment: A jdbc input will return an event for each row in the result set. That is, one person per event. Are you saying you want to combine all those events into a single event that contains an array of persons?

Comment: Yes that's right. it's possible ? create array if doesn't exit and add one by one

Comment: I rewrote the answer to recommend using aggregate.

Comment: Thank you. with the line map['persons'] << { "firstname" => event.get("firstname"), "lastname" => event.get("lastname") }, it's doesn't works. If I put only map['persons'] ||= []. My document is replaced by "_source" : {
    "@version" : "1",
    "id" : "1157731",
    "btrim" : "Lapeyre",
    "@timestamp" : "2021-06-17T08:10:46.229Z"
  }

Comment: I added "action => update" in output, this time I have my fields (I think) but they are not in the persons field, they are at the root of the document.

Comment: Added note on document_id.